# How do I do a decent speech detection?

Tags: signal-processing

I need to write a speech detection algorithm (not speech recognition).

At first I thought I just have to measure the microphone power and compare it to some threshold value. But the problem gets much harder once you have to take the ambient sound level into consideration (for example in a pub a simple power threshold is crossed immediately because of other people talking).

So in the second version I thought I have to measure the current power spikes against the average sound level or something like that. Coding this idea proved to be quite hairy for me, at which point I decided it might be time to research already existing solutions.

Do you know of some general algorithm description for speech detection? Existing code or library in C/C++/Objective-C is also fine, be it commercial or free.

P.S. I guess there is a difference between “speech” and “sound” recognition, with the first one only responding to frequencies close to human speech range. I’m fine with the second, simpler case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key phrase that you need to Google for is [Voice Activity Detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_activity_detection) (VAD) – it's implemented widely in telecomms, particularly in [Acoustic Echo Cancellation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_cancellation) (AEC).

Comment: Thank you! I have seen the phrase before and even Googled for it, but I got scared too early by all the scientific articles in the results. Now I have added “Python” to the query, which made the results much more readable for me :)

Comment: @zoul: make sure to come back here to post your findings